# How to open a port on windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 2008 server on Amazon EC2. I have installed Jboss 7 server on pot 8080 (IIS is running on port 80). When I execute `http://localhost:8080` from within the server on a browser it works fine. But when I access same from outside `http://IPaddress:8080` the request times out. Please note `http://IPaddress` works fine and points to IIS app.

I looked around in this forum and found a couple of useful commands

`netstat -a -n` correctly displays that port 8080 is listening

Then I added 4 rules in Windows firewall, 2 for inbound traffic on port 8080 for UDP and TCP and 2 for outbound traffic on port 8080

Now when I do `netsh firewall show state`, it shows port 8080 for both UDP and TCP under heading "ports currently open on all network interface"

Is there anything I am missing? How can I access port 8080 from Internet for this server

Comment: Is your server connected directly to the internet or do you need to set up a NAT rule for a router / gateway device?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES no idea about that. Actually I am using an existing windows server. Could you please let me know how to check if NAT rules are set on a machine?

Comment: The NAT rules would be set on the router or firewall that sits on the perimeter of the network. I have never worked with EC2 before so I'm not sure if that's the case, but if you have a firewall in place you'll need to set up a rule to allow port 8080 to forward to your server at port 8080. Also make sure that you've set the firewall rules up for Public in the Windows advanced Firewall settings, and not domain or private.

Answer (score 2):

My bad! The issue was actually with Jboss setup. Jboss does not run by default in broadcast mode.

Jboss 7 comes with a setup file standalone.xml which has a tag `<interface name="public">`, this is by default to set to 127.0.0.1. I needed to change it to `<any-address>`

For details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853409/binding-jboss-as7-to-all-interfaces